# What is the difference between using a compose() and a simple flatMap()?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I just watched the conference by **Jake Wharton** [The State of Managing State with RxJava](http://jakewharton.com/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava/).

He proposes to transform the events from view to action in this way:

```
Observable<Event> events = RxView.clicks(view).map(__ -> new Event());
ObservableTransformer<Event, Action> action = events -> events.flatMap(/* ... */);
events.compose(action).subscribe();
```

I would like to know the difference with this implementation:

```
Observable<Event> events = RxView.clicks(view).map(__ -> new Event());    
Observable<Action> action = events.flatMap(/* ... */);
action.subscribe();
```

> What is the difference between using a `compose()` with an
>   [ObservableTransformer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableTransformer.html) and a simple `flatMap()` with two
>   Observable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a good explanation, from Daniel Lew, about the differences. In short:

> The difference is that compose() is a higher level abstraction: it
>   operates on the entire stream, not individually emitted items.

For more details look at the complete explanation in [this article](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/) (in the section named *What About flatMap()?*)